# Problems with NCover 4.5 and Silk4Net (Controls are not identified correctly)

Tags: code-coverage, ncover, silktest

Currently we are using Silk4Net to implement classic regressions GUI tests for a C# WinForms application. We gathered the Code Coverage of those tests via NCover 4.3 and everything worked fine.

Last week we updated NCover to the newest Version (4.5.x) and now it seems that Silk4Net is not able to identify the GUI objects (the Explorer of Silk4Net only finds generic "Control" objects) and not the "real" object type like a Button or so.

Has anybody encountered the same problem like we do currently and did you find a proper solution to get it running again?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Silk Test and the .NET framework are you using? When instrumented for code coverage, does your application run multiple AppDomains? (The easiest way to find out is to look at the process with ProcessExplorer)

Comment: We use SilkTest 14.0 Hotfix 3 and NCover 4.5.2500.554 - regarding the multiple AppDomains, I will check this, but I assume, that we don't have multiple ones

Comment: So i checked that thing with the multiple AppDomains, we don't use that, it's only single one.

Comment: Hm, if you have an active support contract with Borland, this is probably a good occasion to make use of it :)